# Mondrian - Cannot find MDX member exception

Tags: mdx, olap, pentaho, mondrian, rolap

I'm running mondrian as a standalone on mysql. I'm getting the exception `mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Cannot find MDX member '[Measures]'. Make sure it is indeed a member and not a level or a hierarchy.` when i run any MDX query

the catalog xml which is creating issue is

```
       <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="[Measures]" rollupPolicy="partial" access="custom">
                <MemberGrant member="[Measures]" access="none"/>
                <MemberGrant member="[Measures].[X]" access="all"/>
       </HierarchyGrant>
```

Here the hierarchy name and member name are same. This is cause for the issue.

But the same XML works fine on Saiku over mondrian + mysql. 
I used mondrian 3.3 in both the cases. 
help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, edit file mondrian.properties:

```
mondrian.rolap.ignoreInvalidMembers=true

mondrian.rolap.ignoreInvalidMembersDuringQuery=true
```